# Is there a way to test that a pointer's memory allocation has been freed?

Tags: c, unit-testing, pointers, memory-management

Is there a way to tell that a pointer's memory assignment has been deallocated? I am just starting out in C and I think I am *finally* starting to understand the intricacies of memory management in C.

So for example:

```
char* pointer;
pointer = malloc(1024);

/* do stuff */

free(pointer);

/* test memory allocation after this point */
```

I know that the pointer will still store the memory address until I set `pointer = NULL` - but is there a way to test that the pointer no longer references memory I can use, without having to set it to NULL first?

The reason I want to do this is that I have a bunch of unit tests for my C program, and one of them ensures that there are no orphaned pointers after I call a special function which performs a cleanup of a couple of linked lists.  Looking at the debugger I can see that my cleanup function is working, but I would like a way to test the pointers so I can wrap them in a unit test assertion.

Comment: Nope, AFAIK, you can't check if it's deallocated or not.

Comment: Similar (but not quite a duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898823/unit-testing-c-library-memory-management

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standardized memory management that tells you whether or not any given address is part of a currently allocated memory block.

For the purposes of a unit test, you could create a global map that keeps track of every allocation, so you make every allocation go through your custom `malloc` function that adds an entry to the map in debug builds and removes it again in `free`.

Comment: I don't understand by what you mean by a "global map that keeps track of every allocation".  How would I go about that?

Comment: Write any kind of map, like a hash map, that basically stores a bunch of pointers and allows you to quickly look up whether or not a pointer is in this map. In the most primitive form, that could be a simple pre-allocated array that you iterate through. Or it could be a hash map, a tree, you name it. Bottom line - you want to store a list of pointers that had been allocated with malloc, and remove a pointer once you call free on it.

Answer (score 2):

You could always link against an instrumented version of the libraries (say [electric fence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Fence)) for the purposes of unit testing.

Not ideal because you introduce a difference in the production and testing environments.

And some systems may provide sufficient instrumentation in their version of the standard library. For instance the Mac OS 10.5 library supports calling `abort (3)` on double frees, so if your unit tester can trap signals you are home free.

---

Shameless and pointless self promotion: my [little toy c unit testing framework](http://dut.sourceforge.net/) *can* trap signals.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was about to suggest integrating Valgrind (http://valgrind.org) into the test flow.

Comment: @nall: That may be a distinct suggestion, though it has a similar flavor.

Comment: I don't think it's practical in this scenario to use an external library or such. But a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Neither standard C nor POSIX (I think) provides a way to check that.  Your specific operating system *might* have some sort of elaborate black magic for doing this that is only revealed to the Inner Circle of System Programmers, though.

Comment: Why is that?  It seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do isn't it?

Comment: ok...so can i test that the data at the memory address ISNT of the type it should be? In my specific real world case, the pointer points to a struct, can i dereference the pointer and test if the memory address no longer contains the struct that it should.  Ie, if the pointer no longer references a memory location of the correct type, its be deallocated.?

Comment: The actual memory can contain exactly the same data before and after being freed. It could also potentially be unmapped during free (where your unit test could cause a page fault/crash if it tested the contents of previously freed memory).

Answer (score -2):

Use good c practices.  Example:

```
char* pointer = NULL;

/* do stuff */

pointer = malloc(1024);/* malloc does not always work, check it. */

if(pointer == NULL) {
/*Help me, warn or exit*/
}

/* do stuff */

if(pointer) {
    free(pointer);
    pointer = NULL;
}

/* do stuff */

if(pointer) {
/* tested memory allocation stuff */
}
```

Longer, yes, but if you always set a freed pointer to NULL, it's easy to test.

Comment: you can incorporate malloc and free into wrapper functions for the same gain whilst reducing boilerplate as suggested in code complete, mcconnell (well worth a read)

Comment: This is useless in answering the question about how a unit test can determine if a call to `free()` was made.